# JS: Why when I click the button nothing happens?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, onsubmit

I have a form with two text inputs. The second input has a number, that should be changed by the value inside the first input.

When the user clicks a button, the second input should be changed (aumented) in the same percentage that the first input says.

This is my code, that isn´t working: when I click the button nothing happens.

```
Aumentar un <input id="porcentaje">% <input type="button" id="aumentar" value="Aumentar" onclick="calcular()">
<br>Monto: <input id="campo">
```

This is the calcular() function:

```
function calcular() {
var original = document.getElementById('campo').value;
var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje').value;

original = original*aumento/100;
}
```

**[And here is the jsfiddle link to the script.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrNtK/2/)**

Please note that **I´ve not named "submit" the button, nor used onsubmit() because the form already has one submit button.**

Comment: you need to put it back in some field

Comment: I want to change the original field. I´ve tried with innerHTML too.

Comment: document.getElementById('campo').value=original

Comment: For the inputs, put type="text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/NAM7C/

```
calcular = function calcular() {
var original = document.getElementById('campo');
var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje').value;

original.value = (original.value*aumento/100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is closer to your original code, note that in JSFiddle you should set *No wrap - in  body* for your event handler to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9Msj/

```
function calcular() {
var original = document.getElementById('campo');
var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje').value;

original.value = original.value*aumento/100;
}
```